# Parallel.For don't wait for complete all loops

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I have some code which just a few times runs not OK. I mean in 10% of runs it return wrong answer. 
The problem is that, this code some times don't wait for **Parallel.For** to complete all iterations and goes to next steps.

The code is here :

```
List<DataTable> TarazKolsDelimeted = new List<DataTable>(AllDelimetedDatatablesCodeKol.Count);
var res = Parallel.For(0, AllDelimetedDatatablesCodeKol.Count, (taskNumber) =>
{
    var currentTableAsnad = AllDelimetedDatatablesCodeKol[taskNumber];
    var currentTableTarazKol = _dsFullTables.Tables["tarazkol"].Clone();
    calculateTarazDaftar.CalculateTarazKol(currentTableAsnad, ref currentTableTarazKol);
    TarazKolsDelimeted.Add(currentTableTarazKol);
});

if (!res.IsCompleted)
{
    addMemoEdit("Anormal Exit !");
}

foreach (var dataTable in TarazKolsDelimeted) 
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        _dsFullTables.Tables["tarazkol"].ImportRow(dataRow);
    }
}
```

I set if (!res.IsCompleted) for checking but this 'if' can't solve my problem.

Comment: One of the commands in the loop throws an exception?

Comment: @Brannon I don't get any exception, Just some times incomplete answers

Comment: This code doesn't look at all safe. `List<Datatable>` is not thread safe. I suspect this is where your problem lies, not in it exiting prematurely (which I don't believe it does).

Comment: Adding something to a List<T> is not thread safe. Don't modify a List<T> from a Parallel.For. Have a look at ConcurrentBag<T> instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to good comments, I found the answer.

Problem was in

```
TarazKolsDelimeted.Add(currentTableTarazKol);
```

Just I must use lock or ConcurrentBag to fix this problem.

Thanks to All Friends.